# InputStream and a byte array producer?

Tags: java

I have a class which will fetch a fixed-size byte array buffer from a zip file. Is there a way to hook that up to ZipInputStream? It's something like:

```
public class MyByteArrayProducer {
    public boolean hasMoreData();
    public void getNextChunk(byte[] buffer);
}
```

The ZipInputStream class wants an InputStream to read from, but I have to work with the above class.

Thank you

Comment: Look at [Decorator_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) based on the byte array, and then pass this stream to the ZipInputStream constructor.

**--Edit--**

In case that the byte array is too large to keep entirely in memory, you can use piped streams to allow processing of small chunks as they arrive:

```
// Write byte arrays to this stream in the producer thread
PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream(); 

PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(os);
// Read from this stream in the consumer thread
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(in);
```

Comment: I might be misinterpreting - but doesn't that require the full byte array to be passed to the ByteArrayInputStream instance? If so, I can't do that, because it's 1.5gb.